# asyncio call_later runs callback without delay

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to infinitly run a specific function every 5 seconds using asyncio.
I placed `call_later` in the function itself in order to schedule the function to be run after 5 seconds,
but the `call_later` keeps run the function without any delay and result in `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`.

How should I fix this?

Code:

```py
def run(count: int, loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop):
    print(f"run {count}")
    loop.call_later(5, run(count + 1, loop))

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
run(0, loop)

# output:
# run 0
# run 1
# ...
# run 995
# RecursionError
# 
# All these outputs are printed within a second
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues. First, when you write

```
loop.call_later(5, run(count + 1, loop))
```

You are passing the *result* of run as a parameter. That line should be:

```
loop.call_later(5, run, count + 1, loop)
```

Moreover,  do not start it directly, like `run(0, loop)`, but schedule it to run in the loop;

```
loop.call_soon(run, 0, loop)
```